# Is it possible to adapt a device driver such that it works with a very similar other device?

Tags: drivers, osx-mountain-lion, scanner

I am hoping to find a way to adapt a scanner driver such that it works with a very similar scanner.

The scanner I own is the [CanoScan 8000F](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_8000f.html), but unfortunately the driver is only available for PowerPC. As I'm on Mountain Lion, this means that I can't use it.
However, [similar](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_8400f.html) [scanners](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_8800f.html) from the same manufacturer do have drivers that work on Mountain Lion.

Is it possible to adapt these drivers somehow such that they work with the CanoScan 8000F?

Comment: You'd probably need the source code and permission from the source owner to adapt the driver.

Comment: Certainly it's possible to code a device driver so that it works on a range of similar devices.  But to patch a driver to do this, without access to the source code, is "impractical".  (Which is to say only an idiot would try.)  Your only real chance would be if a hex browser revealed some device attribute tables of obvious structure and that you understood how to change.

Comment: Ok, I sort of expected that because the devices are very similar in terms of available functions and specifications I could force the device driver to work with my scanner as well. I thought of this as I had a similar situation with an application that would not work on a certain OS. However, you could edit a file inside the app (don't remember the details) such that it would run nonetheless.

Comment: Upon further research, I found this. http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/mac-osx

Answer (score -1):

Did you try image capture in your Applications folder.  It will work with a wide variety of scanners.

My point was that Apple has support for many, many scanners already built into OS/X and they will work without additional software.  Not all features will be supported but he can probably scan right from image capture.

I have no Canon software installed no this MacBook and it is able to scan from my Canon printer/scanner with no problem

Comment: It'll work with any scanner for which there's a driver, sure. The problem OP is having is that there's no OS X Intel driver available for the scanner he's got.

Comment: The reason for the down vote is that your answer does not solve my problem. My specific scanner, a CanoScan 8000F, does not have a driver for Intel Mac systems. Therefore just connecting it and trying image capture won't work. The link you posted in the other answer (which should just be an edit to your current answer) also shows this. The CanoScan 8000F is not in the list of supported scanners for Mac OS 10.7 and higher.

Comment: Well, when I go to the link it clearly shows the 8000F is supported in 10.9.  Image Capture will work with your scanner.  Your 3rd party app from Hamrick does not work but that is a different story so your question should have been can you modify your 3rd party application.  Good luck to you.  I still do not understand the down vote as I gave you a qualified answer about the driver for the scanner.  It is built into Mavericks.

Comment: @CitizenX Could you please show a screenshot of the site that says the 8000F is supported on 10.9? If you include it in your answer it surely will solve my problem and I can mark your answer as accepted.